# HTTP status - 404 Resource not found exception in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, http-status-code-404, java-ee-6

I have been stuck up with running hello world program in JSP.When i start my server it showing resource not found exception. please help me to solve this problem. I have mentioned my code below

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>MySample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How are you accessing `index.jsp`? I mean URL. Please share directory structure to help you further.

Comment: inside webcontent folder--> inside web-inf folder-->i have mentioned index.jsp

Comment: That is where you went wrong. You have to put `index.jsp` inside WebContent folder not in WEB-INF.

Comment: @Ankiet Kulkarni: It works thanks for identifying my mistake

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829269/http-status-404-resource-not-found-exception-in-jsp#comment34820687_22829269) you had placed file in wrong folder.

Put your `index.jsp` file inside `WebContent` folder. Do not put in `WEB-INF` folder.

---

### WebContent folder

> - **The mandatory location of all Web resources, including HTML, JSP, graphic files, and so on**.
> - If the files are not placed in this directory (or in a subdirectory structure under this directory), the files will not be available when the application is executed on a server.
> - The Web content folder represents the contents of the WAR file that will be deployed to the server. Any files not under the Web content folder are considered development-time resources (for example, .java files, .sql files, and .mif files), and are not deployed when the project is unit tested or published.

### Reference

- [Dynamic Web projects and applications directory structure in Eclipse IDE](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your Welcome index file should start with "/index.jsp" starting with slash if it is directly inside WebContent directory. If it is inside some dirctory like JSP  it should be like /JSP/index.jsp

Comment: inside webcontent folder--> inside web-inf folder-->i have mentioned index.jsp

Comment: its showing 404 only karthi

Comment: @Giridharan which IDE your are using?

Comment: It should work just add index.jsp it should work not WEB-INF is needed just index.jsp or /index.jsp will work

Answer (score 1):

Your directory structure is important that where you have placed the file and provide that path to welcome-file. hope it helps

Comment: inside webcontent folder--> inside web-inf folder-->i have mentioned index.jsp.. I have mentioned WEB-INF/index.jsp but its showing 404 only

Comment: provide that index.jsp in build path.